# How to import an existing project to Git?

Tags: git

I started a coding project, which has expanded in size and I want to use Git for version control. If that matters, the project is combination of web infrastructure written in HTML/CSS/PHP and server infrastructure written in C.

I currently work in the following way:
I perform changes in my development directory: `/var/www/dev`. Once I am satisfied I manually move the changed files to the live directory: `/var/www/stable`. Both stable and dev are currently the same, but are web-accessible through different domains: foo.com and dev.foo.com

I have learned the basics of Git and I am familiar with the commands, but I can`t figure out how to migrate the project, although reading several questions on Stackoverflow. I want to maintain a dev version accessible at dev.foo.com. Should I do it that way:

1. Open /var/www/master and create the repo with: `git init`, `git add .` and `git commit`.
2. Open /var/www/dev and pull the repo with: `git pull file:////var/www/stable .`

Once that is done, I should be able to work in my dev environment and have branches in the dev repo, but how will I push the changes to the stable version? 
Is there a better way to organize that process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a bare repo that you push your work to and fetch changes to the stable directory. Make a clone in the stable directory and another clone where you do the actual work.

In a directory where you keep the bare repo

```
git init --bare
```

In the stable directory

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin <path to bare repo>
git push origin master
```

Create a clone where you do the work

```
git clone <path to bare repo> dev
cd dev
git fetch
...do some work ...
git add .
git commit -m "fix for...."
git push origin master
```

When you are sattisfied with the your work, go back to the stable directory

```
git pull origin
```

This is one way of doing this, you may need to change this workflow so suite your needs.